minimum vertex cover in a general graph
the problem of finding the minimum vertex cover can be solved in bipartite graph .in addition it can be solved in a DAG graph by reducing it to bipartite graph. but why we can't solve this problem in undirected graph but transforming it into DAG then solve the problem. we can transform it to a DAG by this way, if we have an undirected edge between two vertices u and v then change it to be directed edge from the node with min value to the node with max value. this guarantees that the resulted graph is a DAG. Why we can't solve the problem using this technique.
